# Getting values of Fields of a Row of DataFrame - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame which contains several records,

[image]

[image: Image in order to show that the DF contains data]

I want to iterate each row of this DataFrame in order to validate the data of each of its columns, doing something like the following code:

```
val validDF = dfNextRows.map {
    x => ValidateRow(x)
}

def ValidateRow(row: Row) : Boolean =  {
    val nC = row.getString(0)
    val si = row.getString(1)
    val iD = row.getString(2)
    val iH = row.getString(3)
    val sF = row.getString(4)

    // Stuff to validate the data field of each row
    validateNC(nC)
    validateSI(SI)
    validateID(ID)
    validateIF(IF)
    validateSF(SF)
    true
}
```

But, doing some tests, if I want to print the value of the val **nC** (to be sure that I'm sending the corret information to each functions), it doesn't bring me anything:

```
def ValidateRow(row: Row) : Boolean =  {
    val nC = row.getString(0)
    val si = row.getString(1)
    val iD = row.getString(2)
    val iH = row.getString(3)
    val sF = row.getString(4)

    println(nC)

    validateNC(nC)
    validateSI(SI)
    validateID(ID)
    validateIF(IF)
    validateSF(SF)
    true
}
```

[image]

How can I know that I'm sending the correct information to each function (that I'm reading the data of each column of the row correctly)?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spark dataframe function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) should give you a good start.

If your validate functions are simple enough (like checking for null values), then you can embed the functions as

```
dfNextRows.withColumn("num_cta", when(col("num_cta").isNotNull, col("num_cta").otherwise(lit(0)) ))
```

You can do the same for other columns in the same manner just by using appropriate [spark dataframe functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html)

If your validation rules are complex then you can use `udf` functions as

```
def validateNC = udf((num_cta : Long)=> {
   //define your rules here
})
```

You can call the `udf` function using `withColumn` as

```
dfNextRows.withColumn("num_cta", validateNC(col("num_cta")))
```

You can do so for your rest of the validate rules.

I hope to see your problem get resolved soon

Comment: And with the approach that you are mentioning, how could I save the rows that doesn't satisfy the UDF used? Sorry for this dummy questions. Im sow newbie with these Spark and scala things

Comment: you can define `if else` statement in the `udf` function. `if` for the rules and `else` for not satisfying the rules.

Answer (score 2):

`map` is a transformation, you need to apply an [action](https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/apache-spark-examples-of-actions/), for instance you could do `dfNextRows.map(x => ValidaLinea(x)).first`. Spark operates lazily, much like the [Stream](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) class on the standard collections.

Comment: Hello Mr D, I found that in your profile you mentioned that you are interested in collaborating with someone, but you didn't leave an email or other form of contact. Could you add one, please? There's a team I think you would be a good fit in. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomas Zubiri I've updated my profile to include a contact email.